# How to save markdown from a WTForm in a database using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, markdown, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a blog I am making where I create posts in the 'edit' route using markdown in a text area box. However, when I save the post, it converts some of my formatting in weird ways. For instance, when I have an apostrophe, such as in the word `doesn't` it does this:

```
doesn&amp;amp;#39;t
```

Here is the form code:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    __tablename__= 'item'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=False)
    x = db.Column(db.Float)
    y = db.Column(db.Float)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    order = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self,title,content,x,y,category_id,order):
        self.title = title
        self.content = content
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.category_id = category_id
        self.order = order
```

Here is my edit route which handles saving the object in sqlalchemy:

```
@app.route('/edit/<itemid>',methods=('GET','POST'))
@requires_auth
def edit(itemid):
    item = Item.query.get(itemid)
    c = Category.query.get(item.category_id)
    form = ItemForm()
    form.title.data=item.title
    category = c.name
    form.content.data=item.content
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form.get('title'):
            item.title = request.form['title']
            item.content = request.form['content']
            print item.content, 'conetnt'
            db.session.add(item)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('view',itemid=item.id))
        else:
            flash('Title and Content and Category are required.','danger')
    return render_template('edit.html',item=item,form=form, category=category)
```

and here is the template:

```
<div id="container" style="padding:10px">
        <form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('edit',itemid=item.id) }}" id="text-input">
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <div style="margin-left:30px;margin-top:20px;">
                Title: {{ form.title }} {{ category }}
            </div>
            <br>

            <div id="editor">
            {{ form.content( **{':value':'input','@input': 'update'}) }}
                <div id="preview" v-html="compiledMarkdown"></div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-secondary" >
        </form>
</div>
```

as you can see I have an editor which is filled with content using {{ `form.content( **{':value':'input','@input': 'update'}) }}`
Then I am using vue.js to create a markdown preview of the text - which interestingly shows things formatted correctly until it opens a saved file. I believe that the template is passing the data to the server incorrectly. This is because when I print the content in the server code before saving it in the database, it is formatted incorrectly.

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: It appears that your content is getting escaped multiple times. The apostrophe in `don't` is first converted to its numeric character reference: `&#39;`. Then a second round of escaping converts the `&` to its HTML entity: `&amp;`. Finally a third round of escaping converts the second `&` to its HTML entity: `&amp;`. In summary you are getting: `' => &#39; => &amp;#39; => &amp;amp;#39;`. While the first round would be completely acceptable, you need to determine where the second and third round are happening and avoid those.

Comment: hmm I have no idea how to prevent those escaping. Its basically flask wtforms right? Its the one that passes the content into the server

Comment: What is printed in `print item.content` when you save content for the first time? If you see `&#39;`,  try escaping the text using `item.content = Markup.escape(request.form['content'])`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule that doesn't seem to fix it. in fact if I print Markup.escape(request.form['content']) it prints don&#39;t but if I print just request.form['content'], I get the correct, don't

Comment: What version of python, flask, vuejs are you running?

Comment: python is anaconda's 2.7.12. Flask is '0.10', and vuejs is 2.4.2 from 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.js'. Im not sure that vue factors in here? Though I see that vue is formatting markdown correctly where flask is not